How to make multiple existing SwitftData models to conform to Codable by inheriting from base class?
The following is my attempt (with ChatGPT 3.5's help) to implement a base class A: Codable with required init and func encode where I am trying to use reflection to findout B.property1 and C.property2 etc dynamically.
My goal is to convert many such existing SwiftData models into Codable by just inheriting from class A.
So far I have failed to make it work!
I read: SwiftData with Codable and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data and looked into https://github.com/SwiftyLab/MetaCodable. But couldn't make any of them work.
I don't want to add any extra function in model classes (apart of adding inheritance from A) if possible. Is this the write approach for this?
import Foundation

class A: Codable {
    // Attempt to encode/decode dynamically using Mirror
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKey.self)
        
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in mirror.children {
            guard let key = child.label else { continue }
            let value = child.value
            let childType = type(of: value)
            if childType == String.self {
                setValue(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: GenericCodingKey(key)), forKey: key)
            } else if childType == Int.self {
                setValue(try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: GenericCodingKey(key)), forKey: key)
            }
            // Add other types as necessary
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKey.self)
        
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in mirror.children {
            guard let key = child.label else { continue }
            if let value = child.value as? String {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: GenericCodingKey(key))
            } else if let value = child.value as? Int {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: GenericCodingKey(key))
            }
            // Add other types as necessary
        }
    }
    
    struct GenericCodingKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?

        init(_ base: String) {
            self.stringValue = base
            self.intValue = nil
        }

        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
            self.intValue = nil
        }

        init?(intValue: Int) {
            self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"
            self.intValue = intValue
        }
    }
}

@Model class B: A {
    var property1: String = ""

    init(property1: String) {
        self.property1 = property1
        super.init()
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}

@Model class C: A {
    var property2: Int = 0

    init(property2: Int) {
        self.property2 = property2
        super.init()
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}

Any help / pointers into the right direction will be highly appreciated.
TIA

You can’t use inheritance with SwiftData model classes. And Codable doesn’t work well either with SwiftData or at least it’s complicated to get it right.
